# How do I use twig _context within an array?

Tags: arrays, twig

I'm trying to determine if a variable built by concatenating string and a variable is set using a loop within a twig template. I use "_context" to do this in a simple example and it works fine for individual variables:

php file:

```
$text_1 = 'some text one';
$text_2 = 'some text two';
$text_3 = 'some text three';
```

twig file:

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
    <span>{{ _context["text_" ~ i] }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

But now I'm trying to do the same thing with an array variable, where the keys are built by concatenating string and a variable

php file:

```
$product = array(
    'bullet_1' => 'some text one',
    'bullet_2' => 'some text two',
    'bullet_3' => 'some text three',
);
```

But none of my attempts to get them from the twig file seem to be working:
I've tried each of the following to no avail

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
    {{ _context["product.bullet_" ~ i]] }}
{% endfor %}
```

fail

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
    {{ product._context["bullet_" ~ i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

fail

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
    {{ product[_context["bullet_" ~ i]] }}
{% endfor %}
```

fail

Any ideas?

Comment: If you pass `$product` as `$twig->render('template.twig', [ 'product' => $product, ]);` it should be `_context['product']['bullet_'~i]`

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you!! That was it!